# How can i get access to a canvasJS chart through a DOM-Container

Tags: javascript, canvasjs

When i render a canvasJS-chart to a div container, how can i get access to the chart object through the div-Container? i dont want to make the chart variable global.

I want to use it as: var chart=$(“#container”).canvasJS();

Any ideas please.

Answer in this link is not working
https://canvasjs.com/forums/topic/how-can-i-get-access-to-a-canvasjs-chart-through-a-dom-container/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access Chart-Container in CanvasJS jQuery Charts using `$("#container").CanvasJSChart();`. In your case it may not be working as you are using lowercase **c** in  **CanvasJS()**, .

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to [include a jQuery plugin](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/integration/jquery/) before that method works:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/jquery.canvasjs.min.js"></script>`

If you've already included that and it's still not working, the container must not be a true CanvasJS container. If it really *really* is a CanvasJS container, then this appears to be a bug you should file with the creators.

Answer (score 0):

Include [jQuery Plugin](https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/jquery.canvasjs.min.js)  for CanvasJs chart https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/jquery.canvasjs.min.js
and access canvasJs chart by using

```
$("#chartContainer").CanvasJSChart()
```

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/QwZuf/920/)

Also see [Updated answer](https://canvasjs.com/forums/topic/how-can-i-get-access-to-a-canvasjs-chart-through-a-dom-container/#post-19812) in CanvasJs forum.