# Get CanvasJS chart's instance from DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvasjs

My chart is defined as

```
var myChart = new CanvasJS.Chart("myChartContainer", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    axisY :{
        includeZero: false,
        gridColor: "rgba(140, 140, 140, 1)"
    },
    toolTip: {
        shared: true,
        content: false
    },
    legend: {
        fontSize: 13
    },
    data: myChartData.json
});
```

And I need to access the chart's instance via its DOM element (I don't want to make `myChart` a global variable. I've tried retrieving the chart's instance using these two methods

```
var charr = $('#myChartContainer').CanvasJS()
var charr = $('#myChartContainer').CanvasJSChart()
```

But none of them work. The first throws `jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).CanvasJS is not a function`, and the second just returns an undefined object. I am using the jQuery plugin of CanvasJS.

What am I missing? How can I retrieve the chart's instance?

FYI, I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49043776/how-can-i-get-access-to-a-canvasjs-chart-through-a-dom-container) answer, but it didn't help.

Comment: Can you clarify why you don't want to make it a global variable? You can use an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code sample that you have shared, you seem to be using jQuery plugin of CanvasJS but creating chart JavaScript way. As per [CanvasJS jQuery documentation](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/integration/jquery/), you can create chart as `$("#myChartContainer").CanvasJSChart(chartOptions);` & then you can get the reference to the chart as `$("#myChartContainer").CanvasJSChart();`. Working example shown below.

```js
var options = {
  title: {
     text: "CanvasJS jQuery Chart"
  },
  data: [{
    type: "line",
    dataPoints: [
        { x: 1, y: 63 },
        { x: 2, y: 69 },
        { x: 3, y: 65 },
        { x: 4, y: 70 },
        { x: 5, y: 71 },
        { x: 6, y: 65 },
        { x: 7, y: 73 },
        { x: 8, y: 96 },
        { x: 9, y: 84 },
        { x: 10, y: 85 },
        { x: 11, y: 86 },
        { x: 12, y: 94 },
        { x: 13, y: 97 },
        { x: 14, y: 86 },
        { x: 15, y: 89 }
    ]
   }]
};
$("#chartContainer").CanvasJSChart(options);

var chart = $("#chartContainer").CanvasJSChart(); //Get reference to the chart instance
/*chart.options.title.text = "New Title";
chart.render();*/
```

```html
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/jquery.canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

Comment: Okay, so there’s no way to get the chart’s instance if the chart is created the JavaScript way? It’s only possible with the jQuery way?

And are there any “side-effects” I should know about if I change my chart to being created with jQuery as opposed to how it is now? Or would they behave exactly the same way?

Comment: CanvasJS jQuery plugin is just a wrapper for CanvasJS JavaScript chart - which lets you do things the jQuery way. There are no side-effects or any difference between them apart from the way it's been used. jQuery plugin allows you to get the chart instance using `$("#myChartContainer").CanvasJSChart();` if it's created using jQuery plugin ( `$("#myChartContainer").CanvasJSChart(chartOptions);` ).